# Changing the log in screen in windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, login-screen

Is there anyway you can change the login screen picture (colour) in windows 8, in a picture / wallpaper?

I'm not talking about the pre-login screen where you can see the time and what not. But the login screen where you need to fill in your password. This is currently blue with me.

Comment: this is not possible, only the color. You can only change the lockscreen picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page: https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=27428 appears to answer your question.

If that's not it, try this - I've used this method personally.

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/15554-sign-screen-change-background-color-windows-8-a.html
Method one changes pictures, but I'm not as sure it will work:

> Create the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Personalization if it does not exist.
>
> Make a new string `LockScreenImage`.
>
> Set it's value equal to the path to your image file. For safety, I'd recommend a path without spaces.

Method two changes colors but not pictures:

> From the Start Screen, type run and press Enter.
>
> Type regedit in the open text box and click OK. If prompted by User Account Control, click Yes.
>
> In the Registry Editor, navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Accent.
>
> Within Accent, check to see if you have a DWORD value titled DefaultColorSet.
>
> If this value already exists, proceed to the next step.
>      If this value does not exist, right-click somewhere in the empty space within the right-hand pane for Accent, and click New > DWORD (32-bit) Value. Type DefaultColorSet and press Enter.
>
> In the right-hand pane for Accent, double-click on DefaultColorSet to edit the value.
>
> In the window that appears, select the Decimal radio button and enter a new number in the Value data: field. See the chart below for color values:
>
> [image]

Comment: "Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Answer (score 0):

The login screen in Windows 8 is attached to the background color you choose in the Personalize menu. You change the color but it will change ethe way the start menu looks and etcetera.

If you find a separate registry that would allow you to specify an image path like the way Windows 7 worked your problem will be solved.